# how to get the regex from the query param input where the delimiter is "&" and even the regex contains "&"?

Tags: node.js, regex, string-operations

i have a scenario where i will get input as path and query param and in the place of value i will get a regex.

regex input contains & which is a delimiter in query param.

```
`Input :` '/austin/query.html?dept=([^&]*)&group=([^&]*)'
```

i want to get this regex `([^&]*)` from query param dynamically.

Any idea or suggestions might be silly / basic question please do help ?

Comment: What specific problem are you having? It should be URL-encoded in the URL.

Comment: @DaveNewton : when i try to split using '&'  iam getting output like this { dept: '([^', ']*)': [ '', '' ], group: '([^' } since & is a delimiter. i am expecting output like this [([^&]*),([^&]*)] picking the 2 regex from the input

Comment: @DaveNewton means that the input should be URL-encoded. So, the input should actually be: `/austin/query.html?dept=([^%26]*)&group=([^%26]*)`. This would make parsing much simpler on the server.

Comment: Thanks thgaskell and DaveNewton . perfect way to fix.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Why would you split at all? Use a url processor.

Comment: @Dave Can you give me more details i am currently using url module in node js. do recommend if there is any other better way to do .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to URL encode query parameters before the request is sent. This helps to avoid issues with characters that have special meaning (`?`, `=`, `&`, `#`, etc.)

So instead of sending literal ampersand characters `&` in the regex, it should be URL-encoded to be `%26` instead.

```
/austin/query.html?dept=([^%26]*)&group=([^%26]*)
```

When this parsed by the `querystring` module, it will automatically be converted back to the ampersand character.

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const URL = require('url');

function parseQueryParamsFromUrlPath(urlPath) {
  const { query } = URL.parse(urlPath);
  return querystring.parse(query);
}

parseQueryParamsFromUrlPath('/austin/query.html?dept=([^%26]*)&group=([^%26]*)');
// Output: { dept: '([^&]*)', group: '([^&]*)' }
```